# Is it possible to select the next cell each day from a list in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know this is kind of an odd question, but I have a list of urls that I need to cycle through and display that url in a separate cell, and it needs to automatically change each day. And then finally, once it reached the end of the list to go back to the top of the list.

Is this something that is even possible to accomplish on Google Sheets, or do I need to take a completely different approach?

**EDIT:** Here is a rough example of what I am trying to do, and I honestly don't know where to start, so I haven't tried much yet. I know how to display the last row in a column, but I cant figure out how to auto change that last row each day. I feel like the best way to do this would be to either move the top row to the bottom each day, or vice versa, but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

[image: Google Sheets Example]

Please let me know if you have any suggestions/if I can clarify anything... Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with some example of how many links you wish to circle trough

Comment: Please can you share what you have already tried? What isn't working and an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I just added a bit more above, please let me know if that answered your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this very much possible, I have made one example sheet for you and you can make copy of the same.

[Example Sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17jI2OuiYILvE15D4htjb5eVu6lk5oU3Km4Phxz2RGYI/edit#gid=0)

E2 Contains Today's date, F2 contains date for comparison, G2 is the difference between 2 dates which will go on increasing daily, there will be automatic increment in the Column H.

Based on daily increment in Column H you will get your Urls in Column B.

You don't need to start list from the beginning again, you can go on adding list in Column A. However still if you will need then you can manipulate formulas by comparing another date.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like this is on the right track, but from what I am seeing it just lists the possible urls for the next few days. I need it to just display one url each day, and then switch to the next one at a specific time, say like right before midnight so it displays the next url slightly before the next day is upon us. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I have made some changes in the sheet, you can check now. Now only one url will appear daily and you can also mention a date from when you want swich to be effective.

Comment: Perfect, thats exactly what I needed! Now the last step would be to automatically change the date each Sunday or something like that so the list just keeps going, is that possible? Just thinking it would make it easy since there will only be a limited amount of urls. It would make it function exactly as I was hope, I feel like that shouldn't be too difficult to accomplish either, and it would cut down on human error. i.e. Me, haha. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: I have added Sheet2, pls check.

Comment: I guess this does answer the question in a sense, but I would prefer to not assign a different url to each day since there will be 4 and I need them to alternate days evenly. Also the urls will chang very rarely so I should be alright with updating those by hand, but would like to "select" or mark the next url each day automatically so I can have Zapier read it and send it over SMS to a group of people each day, and then go back to the top when it gets to the end of the list. I'm starting to think this would be more of a script... Is it doable, or should I try to take a different approach?